# Roxyfileman filemanager integration

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to integrate roxyfileman filemanager with tinymce 4. When I click on filemanager I can able to see filemanager, But when I select any image I am getting below error message in console. and image is also not getting inserted.

Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Later I found, open manager. It doesn't require any configuration nothing. All you need to do is just download from below link and place it into your project folder. Thats it.

Reference: http://www.designsandcode.com/261/open-manager-tinymce-file-manager/